# connection to database failed from php file to phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, xampp

I am trying to run an old project i had to use it again now. now, previously it worked fine. but now for some reason, its failing to connect to the localhost database of phpmyadmin.

All i want for now is for the connection to work. xampp has both APache and MySQL running on the default ports, so these are good to go. in fact, i know they are because i opened a different project and its able to connect fine.

basically this is the portion of my php file that attempts connection to the database:

```html
<?php
 //DataBase
 
 if ( !( $database = mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "" ) ) )
      die( "<p>Connection to DataBase failed!</p>" );

?>
```

when i run the file in chrome (using notepad++) i get this error first thing:

> Connection to DataBase failed! " ); 
>   if ( !mysqli_select_db(
>   $database,"courseregisteration" ) ) die( " Failed to open DataBase!

now of course the database wont open since the connection is not established!

so i have no idea why its not connecting. i dont have a password, so these parameters are the typical default parameters for this to work.

any help please?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work with no password, try adding a password and use it accordingly?

Comment: @Charle Steynberg my friend tried it on his computer today without a passwird and it connected fine

Comment: i think you should gave the name of database as a parameter in you mysqli_connect isn't it !! check this manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: @Rmidi Ayoub But my second function is the one that does that. I havent posted it in the code snippet, but you can actually see it in the error I have. Plus, I also tried including the dB name along the other parameters, but it still didn't work. As mentioned, my friend tried it on his without changing the file and the connection worked for him just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this, but do it on a separate .php connection

```
<?php
$hostname = "locahost";
$database = "your db";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$db mysql_pconnect($hostname, $username, $password)or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database,$db);
session_start();

$qry = "YOUR QUERY HERE";
$result = mysql_query($qr);
while($qry = mysql_fetch_array($result))
}
//some code here
{
?>
```

Comment: May I ask wat you mean by separate .PHP connection? You mean in a new file?

Comment: @goldensunplayer yes, for example. You have a HTML file and you want to connect to PHP. you must have a new file that the extension is .php, like "connection.php".

Comment: actually the file is alrdy in .PHP extention

Comment: then use that answer I provide, then connect it into html, for example in a <form>, you can use this <form action="your connection here" method="POST" ></form> did you try this?

Comment: Thts kinda complicating things. It worked for my friend, and it used to work for me previously, without all this complication. I'm gonna try your code and see wat happens

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    <?php
 //create connection
 $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345','company');

//check connection
 if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))
 {
    echo 'Failed to connect to database: '.mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
    echo 'Connected Successfully!!';
?>
```

In the above code we are connecting the .php page to the database.

To create a connection mysqli_connect() method is used.
Parameters passed to the mysqli_connect() functions are the hostname, phpmyadmin username, phpmyadmin password and the database name.

This connection string is stored in a variable named $connect.
Next we first have to check whether we are connected to database successfully or not.
For that we use if—else conditional statement.
The function mysqli_connect_errno($connect) checks if there is any error in the connection string. If there is any error, it will return true otherwise false.
If there is any error, it will be displayed by the echo statement in if block otherwise Connected Successfully!! Message will be displayed.
The function mysqli_connect_error() function is used to display system error message.
Just open the browser and run the connect.php.
You will get the following output: "Connected Successfully".

Comment: i dont get a blank page. neither an error. all i get is a page thats showing the php code

Comment: You can find which application is using this port using CMD command : netstat -ano | findstr 3306, so that we can figure out if its not a port conflict of MYSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your connection code to an Object Oriented Conn:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","my_db");

// Check connection
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
  exit();
}
?>
```